# How to fix : 'undefined reference to foo()' with Makefile and g++

Tags: c++, linker

I've been trying to get into C++ again, and I have a linker error when I try to compile :

main.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `eval(std::string, double, double, double)'

I've already tried compiling each file separatly and then linking by hand but it never works.

I have tried numerous solutions provided by other similar posts but none of these work and I don't have any idea on how to fix my problem (which doesn't seem to be that hard)

main.cpp :

```cpp
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0

#include <iostream>
#include "functions.h"


int main()
{
    std::string expression = "1/2+x";
    double x = 1.45;
    double y = 1.65;
    double z = 1.77;

    double result = 0.0;

    result = eval(expression,x,y,z);    

    std::cout << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

functions.cpp :

```cpp
#include "functions.h" 

double eval(std::string expression_s, double x, double y, double z)
{
        typedef exprtk::symbol_table<double> symbol_table_t;
        typedef exprtk::expression<double>     expression_t;
        typedef exprtk::parser<double>             parser_t;

        symbol_table_t symbol_table0;
        symbol_table_t symbol_table1;
    symbol_table_t symbol_table2;

        expression_t   expression;
        parser_t       parser;

        symbol_table0.add_variable("x",x);
        symbol_table1.add_variable("y",y);
    symbol_table2.add_variable("z",z);

        expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table0);
        expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table1);
        expression.register_symbol_table(symbol_table2);

        parser.compile(expression_s,expression);

    std::cout << expression.value();

    return expression.value();

}
```

functions.hpp :

```cpp
ifndef FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define FUNCTIONS_H_INCLUDED

#include "exprtk/exprtk.hpp"
#include <iostream>

double eval(std::string expression_s, double x, double y, double z);

#endif
```

Makefile :

```
CC = g++
EXEC = Crystal_MET
LIBS = 
FLAGS = 

all: main.o
    $(CC) *.o -o $(EXEC) $(LIBS)

main.o : functions.o main.cpp functions.h
    $(CC) main.cpp -c $(FLAGS)

functions.o : functions.cpp functions.h
    $(CC) functions.cpp -c $(FLAGS)

clear :
    rm -f *.o

mr_proper :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
```

Comment: I suggest you start relying on the [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) of `make`. That way all you really need is to list the object files in the main executable target (which should be a separate target from the `all` target). The compiler will then compile and link your application automatically. That means the only rule you really need is `$(EXEC): main.o functions.o` without any commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.cpp is compiled against a different ABI than functions.cpp because of :

```
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI 0
```

Either remove that line from main.cpp, or add it to functions.cpp .

More details : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Comment: Wow thanks a lot it worked ! I didn't know I had to use it in every .cpp files

Comment: You could also pass it as a compiler flag : `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` (by eg. adding it to `FLAGS` in your makefile).

Comment: @Neh Why do you use it at all? Especially without knowing what it does?

Comment: The catch here is that with different ABIs `std::string` may be seen by linker as complete different data types (different size, layout etc.).

Comment: @jszpilewski : not "may" - they *are* different : `std::__cxx11::string` vs. `std::string`.